# AngularJS - Updating a variable in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have declared a variable in parent scope in one of my controllers.

> $scope.myValue = true;

This value is fetched in the custom directive easily. But when the value is updated in the parent controller it is not reflected in the custom directive.

My question is how can we let the directive know that the "myValue" is changed?

If the info is not suffice kindly let me know.

Comment: create a service, add this variable to that service, inject this service into controller as well as directive and there you go

Comment: Can't you `$watch` it inside the directive?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv  tried $watch. But it is called only once. ie., when view is loaded.

Comment: Then it probably means you are overwriting the reference you are `$watch`ing _or_ are not `$apply`ing (through some built-in AngularJS directive like `ng-click` or manually) when you change it in the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent controller, upon changing the value of the variable, you can broadcast an event like this -

```
$scope.$broadcast('valueChanged', {
     val: $scope.myValue // pass in any object you want
});
```

And then in your child controllers, handle it like -

```
$scope.$on('valueChanged', function (event, data) {
     console.log(data); // get the same object here
});
```

`$broadcast` fires the event down, so this should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the value inside the directive, like this:

```
app.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function($scope){
            $scope.$watch('$parent.myValue', function(newVal){
                console.log(newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Link demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mzrja04L/